# It looks like a button, but it is not an input element. How can such an element be created?

Tags: html, css

It looks like a button, but it is not an input element. How can such an element be created?

Comment: Please, could you make you question clearer? Do you mean a hyperlink made to took like a button? Which can expand.

Comment: I second that. You really need to clarify your question.

Comment: There is a technique called sliding doors in web development. You can use it to make a hyperlink expandable horizontal and vertically (with a little tweak. I will post an answer on this if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it is [a button](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp) element? Or [img](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp) element  with a image of a button?

Answer (score 1):

1. it can be a `<button>`
2. It can be anything with the right `border`
3. it can be an image.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an image, or you could style a div (or other block level element) around some text. You could then make it behave a bit more "buttony" with javascript effects. Quite why you'd want to do that is beyond me though.

Answer (score 0):

They're normally created by adding CSS styling to a standard hyperlink, sometimes in combination with javascript. Check out [Top 10 CSS buttons tutorials](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/top-10-css-buttons-tutorial-list).